# reactor-netty trailerHeaders not working with body in HttpServerResponse

Tags: netty, reactor-netty

reactor-netty trailerHeaders not working with body in HttpServerResponse. If send called trailers not passed to client.
If send not called trailers pass to client.

Simple server with send method

```
DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create()
                        .port(8083)
                        .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C)
                        .handle((request, response) -> {
                            return response
                                    .status(200)
                                    .header(HttpHeaderNames.TRAILER, "grpc-status")
                                    .chunkedTransfer(true)
                                    .trailerHeaders(s -> {
                                        s.add("grpc-status", "0");
                                    })
                                    .sendString(Mono.just("d"));
                        })
                        .bindNow();

        server.onDispose()
                .block();
```

Do request to server

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/api.Ping/GetPing  --http2-prior-knowledge -H 'Content-Type: application/grpc' --data-binary "@myfile.dat"  -v
....
> content-length: 48
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 4294967295)!
< HTTP/2 200
< trailer: grpc-status
< content-length: 1
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
d
```

Threis no trailerHeaders.

And if I disable sendString:

```
    public static void server() {
        DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create()
                        .port(8083)
                        .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C)
                        .handle((request, response) -> {
                            return response
                                    .status(200)
                                    .header(HttpHeaderNames.TRAILER, "grpc-status")
                                    .chunkedTransfer(true)
                                    .trailerHeaders(s -> {
                                        s.add("grpc-status", "0");
                                    });
//                                    .sendString(Mono.just("d"));
                        })
                        .bindNow();

        server.onDispose()
                .block();
    }
```

trailerHeaders appear

```
> content-length: 48
>
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 4294967295)!
< HTTP/2 200
< trailer: grpc-status
<
< grpc-status: 0
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 2):

`Mono.just("d")` and `Flux.just("d")` are considered as something that defines completely the message and are not considered chunked. I slightly modified your example and it shows that the trailing headers work as expected when we use `Flux.just("1", "2", ...)` basically more than one element which is considered `chunked` message.

```
DisposableServer server =
            HttpServer.create()
                    .port(8083)
                    .protocol(HttpProtocol.H2C)
                    .handle((request, response) -> {
                        return response
                                .status(200)
                                .header(HttpHeaderNames.TRAILER, "grpc-status")
                                .chunkedTransfer(true)
                                .trailerHeaders(s -> {
                                    s.add("grpc-status", "0");
                                })
                                .sendString(Flux.just("d1", "d2"));
                    })
                    .bindNow();

    server.onDispose()
            .block();
```